# How do you add reference to general comments in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, comments, doc

Adding references to comments is pretty well documented, and works well for linking between items in Visual Studio.

```
/// text for class TestClass
public class TestClass
{
    /// <summary>DoWork is a method in the TestClass class.
    /// <para>Here's how you could make a second paragraph in a description. <see cref="System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)"/> for information about output statements.</para>
    /// <seealso cref="TestClass.Main"/>
    /// </summary>
    public static void DoWork(int Int1)
    {
    }

    /// text for Main
    static void Main()
    {
    }
}
```

But how do I get it to work in general comments?
Where you may have blocks of comments above the namespace, or in general code where you need other programmers to see more than just the code.
When I try the following, Visual Studio doesn't anything special with it, unlike when it is in /// and precedes a class or method.

```
/*
  First Line to Comment. Maybe a Copyright
  Second Line to Comment
  Third Line to Comment
  Some other junk where users should look at <seealso cref="TestClass.Main"/>    
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This only works in doc-comments, also called XML-comments introduced with `///`.

C# can create XML-files from these comments if the corresponding option is set in the project options. External tools like [Sandcastle Help File Builder](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB) or [NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/) can create help files by using the information in the XML-files plus information reflected from the assemblies.

These references are inserted in the resulting help files. They would make little sense in ordinary comments, as those are ignored by the C# compiler.

**But *Sandcastle Help File Builder* and *NDoc* allow you to add a project summary and namespace summary comments to the generated help files.**

Comment: I disagree that it would make no sense: it can be very annoying, if you mention a class/member in a comment and the comment is not updated when you refactor/rename that class/member.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is that you don't.

Triple forward slash comments are defined as XML Documentation tags, and they can be parsed by VS and turned into web documentation.

But the general double slash and multi line comments are just totally ignored.